# How To Display Related Product Images On The Left In product page

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to display the product images on the left side which are at the bottom of  in the product page image

[image]

i also tried to find the code of these images in the local.xml but i am unable to find it

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: not worked with the previous answer !